# why not operator in javascript excute the first part of if statement?

Tags: javascript

i am trying to check `if(a==b)` then `if(c==d)` and after that `if(a and b values) != (b and c values)`.

```
var a = 3;
var b = 3;
var c = 4;
var d = 4;

if ((a == b) != (c == d)){
  document.write('Yes');
}else{
    document.write('No');
}
```

Why not operator in javascript excute the first part of if statement?

Comment: `a == b` returns `true`, not `3` ...

Comment: @Teemu Surely a == b will return true if both are 3? Effectively, the logic of this line is - if (True != True)

Comment: `a == b` returns `true`, so does `c == d`, after that your if statement is `if (true != true)` so it should write "No"

Comment: @Alex Hmm ... Obviously I've been considering glasses too long, code lines seems to dance on the screen = ).

Comment: OP's confusing `=` and `==` it seems

Comment: @AndrewLi how's that?

Comment: @AndrewLi a = b would be false, as they're not the same object. Similarly, c = d would be false, so it would be (false != false), would would return false.

Comment: @Alex That makes no sense. `a = b` would result in `b` being assigned the value of `a` and would evaluate to `b`, which is 3... `=` is *an assignment operator*.

Comment: @AndrewLi Sorry, you're absolutely correct. I've been burning the candle at both ends trying to fix a very persistent bug and didn't think that comment through.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine , answer is NO ..

I update answer !

```js
var a = 3;
var b = 3;
var c = 4;
var d = 4;

if ((a == b) != (c == d)){
  document.write('Yes');
}else{
  document.write('No');
}

/*

a == b   ==>  TRUE
c == d   ==>  TRUE

(TRUE != TRUE)  ==>  FALSE 

Answer NO is correct 


*/
```

I suggest this code for you :

```js
var a = 3;
var b = 3;
var c = 5;
var d = 5;

if (   a == b == c == d   ){
  document.write('Yes');
}else{
  document.write('NO');
}
```

Comment: He wants to check if a and b is not equals to c and d so answer is not "No" i quess because a = b and c = d and also a and b is not equals to c and d. All should return true for that case that he wants to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Operators that we are using in `if` statements are returning `boolean` values ( `true` or `false` ). So your if statement is checking:

- `if(a==b)` and returns `true`,
- `if(c==d)` and retuns `true`,
- `if(true != true)` returns `false` and it goes to `else`.

you have to use this like that:

```js
var a = 3;
var b = 3;
var c = 4;
var d = 4;

if(a == b && c==d && a != c)
{
    document.write('Yes');
}
else
{
    document.write('No');
}
```

so first it will check if `a==b` then `d==c` if it's okey so checking if `a != c` is enough to get answer that you want.